# Rename All Files In Folders Java

Tags: java, file, directory

I have one folder which contains many sub-folders. To make it more clear here is an example of the folders:

`Movies:
    MovieTitle:
        Moviefile.mp4        (Movie File)
        MovieSubtitles.srt   (Subtitles)
    MovieSeries:
        MovieTitle:
            Moviefile.mp4
            MovieSubtitles.srt`

I need to rename each mp4 and srt file to the following "MovieTitle". If the movie is part of a series it should be named to Series "Title + Movie Title". Lets use Star Wars as an example for series and how to name. "Star Wars" would be the name of a directory in "Movies". In "Star Wars" are 6 Folders each with a mp4 and srt file in it. For episode 1 of star wars the mp4 and srt file should be renamed to: "Star Wars - Episode 1.mp4" and "Star Wars - Episode 1.srt". If Episode 1 was not part of series it should be named to just "Episode 1.mp4"

Here is the code that I have come up with so far:

```
    public static void renaming(File[] files){
    String dir1, dir2;
    for(File movie: files){ //Main folder containing all of the movies.
        dir1 = movie.getName();
        for(File filesInMovie: movie.listFiles()){
            if(filesInMovie.isDirectory()){ //This means that it is a series.
                dir2 = filesInMovie.getName();
                for(File i: filesInMovie.listFiles()){
                    i.renameTo(dir1 + " - " + dir2);
                }
            }else{
                filesInMovie.renameTo(dir1)
            }               
        }

    }
}
```

I realize that renameTo is an actual function in Java. I thought it would rename files until I read what it actually does (which I am still a little fuzzy on). So my main question is how would I get this code to properly rename the files.

Just some extra things you should know:
    One Directory Contains all of the movies.
    There are possibilities for each folder in the movies folder
        It has other folders in it (It is a series)
        It has a mp4 and srt file in it
If you have any questions please ask!!!

Comment: Do you use Java 6 or Java 7+?

Comment: @fge I am using java 7

Comment: Are you also using Guava? Because if you do it's going to be very easy!

Comment: @fge I am not currently using that. In fact, never heard of it. What is it?

Comment: See [here](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/); it is a very powerful library

Answer (score 0):

Using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) and Java 7, here is what you can do:

```
public final class Renamer
{
    private static final Joiner JOINER = Joiner.on(" - ");

    private static final class RenamerVisitor
        extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>
    {
        private final Path baseDir;

        private RenamerVisitor(final Path baseDir)
        {
            this.baseDir = baseDir;
        }

        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(final Path file,
            final BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            throws IOException
        {
            final Path relpath = baseDir.relativize(file);
            final String targetName
                = JOINER.join(Iterables.transform(relpath,
                Functions.toStringFunction()));
            final Path dstPath = baseDir.resolve(targetName);
            System.out.printf("'%s' -> '%s'\n", file, dstPath);
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    }

    public static void main(final String... args)
        throws IOException
    {
        final Path baseDir = Paths.get("/home/fge/tmp/jsr203/docs");
        Files.walkFileTree(baseDir, new RenamerVisitor(baseDir));
    }
}
```

This is for my environment in a directory. Sample output:

```
[...]
'/home/fge/tmp/jsr203/docs/java/io/class-use/File.html' -> '/home/fge/tmp/jsr203/docs/java - io - class-use - File.html'
'/home/fge/tmp/jsr203/docs/java/io/class-use/FilePermission.html' -> '/home/fge/tmp/jsr203/docs/java - io - class-use - FilePermission.html'
'/home/fge/tmp/jsr203/docs/java/io/File.html' -> '/home/fge/tmp/jsr203/docs/java - io - File.html'
```

In order to make it use the "real thing", replace the `System.out.println()` in `visitFile` with [`Files.move()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) and you're done!

Of course, you can also choose to copy instead, [or even create a (hard) link if your filesystem supports it](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-).

Side note: unlike `File`'s `.renameTo()`, `Files.move()` does not silently fail!

(and after that, you should drop Java 6's old file API fast)

Answer (score 0):

[`File#getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) returns a String. You are using this to get the name of the current file and then attempting to rename the file using `File#rename(String)` where the method is actually defined as [`File#renameTo(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29). That is it the argument is expected to be a file to where you are attempting to rename the file.

Some Suggestions:

1. Look at [`Files.move()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) use this to move the file to target - Link has example of this
2. Don't use the get name method for the first directory - use the file directly (Something like below but still not correct I think) and this is if you want the file in the same base directory `movies`

   ```
   i.renameTo(new File(movie," - " + filesInMovie.getName() + ext);
   ```

   Still needs work for extension of file `ext` however which will come from the file `i`